# prevent duplicate ajax posts to webmethod on server side

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I'm using ASP.Net Web Forms , I have a button client side that posts data to a webmethod server side through jquery ajax.  My question is how can I prevent the webmethod from recieving multiple requests from the user clicking the button more then once, I would like this code to be server side if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the button is clicked on the page, disable it so a second click will not register, and then send the request and take the appropriate action once you get the response back.

To do this server side would be difficult, you would probably have to serialize the requests and then compare each one to a recent history and determine if its a duplicate. This could be difficult because there might be legitimate duplicates, and distinguishing between them could be difficult.

Comment: you think .on() and .off() for handeling the click event of the button is better then using session to  store all parameters of request , then checking next request to session on server side ?? @Bill

Comment: I set click of button with .on() then right before the ajax i could use .off() , then in success: I could turn it back on()  - there are sometimes for what ever reason that It just doesn't work , then clicking the button again makes it work , so I was thinking server side was a better way of checking - I'm always more comfortable with everything server side

Comment: Yes, because duplicate checking can get really complicated. If the requests come in and are processed by the server at the same time, you've got to somehow detect and then prevent that, which can get complicated.

Comment: makes sense - I kinda thought I was getting in over my head trying to check server side